# Where I can find old pipeline plugins and its related dependencies for Jenkins 1.658?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are in the process of migrating to Jenkins 2 (we anticipate to get migration done in the next 2 months). But Unfortunately our current **Jenkins 1.658** stopped working while we tried to installed `Clean-up Workspace` plugin, which upgraded the pipeline plugins and made it in-compatible with the Jenkins 1.X core.

Unfortunately rolling back/removing the plugins didn't fix the problem. The pipeline is still not working.

Trying to manually find those plugin and replace them in the `JENKINS_HOME/plugins`.

Is there by any chance can you pls help me with the following:

1. Where can I find the pipeline plugins and its related dependencies that is compatible with the older version of Jenkins(**Jenkins 1.658**)?
2. Possibly are you able to provide a the list of pipeline plugins and its related dependencies along with its version.

Or if you have a better suggestion to fix my problem please do let me know.

Any help is really appreciated!!!

Comment: did you tried to stop using "clean-up workspace" plugin and switch to the cleanWs() provided by pipelines ? As well as all try to read here about plugins - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/

Comment: By clean-up workspace I mean "CleanWs()". Yeah, we removed CleanWs(). But it did not roll back the pipeline plugins that were updated.